# Google Style Wizard

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-style-guide

I beginning to use google style wizard, and i was wondering to know if it is possible coloring the streets (example: local street) in different colours by area determined. I would be really gratefull if you could tell me how to do it in android studio 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a `json` file to style your map defining the features that you want to style and the stylers (In the example I'm styling local roads with red color).

**style_json.json**

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then you will need to apply the style to the map:

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/style-reference) you can find the style reference.

Take into account that according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) styling works only on the `normal` map type.

Also note that this styling applies to the whole map. You can't for example style local roads in red for the USA and in blue for Europe out of the box, but you can emulate this behaviour using an `OnCameraIdleListener` and styling the map with different `json` files based on the `CameraPosition` (`target`, `zoom`, `bearing`, `zoom`). For example (styling local roads using `R.raw.style_json` if `latitude > 40.4` and using `R.raw.style_json2` otherwise):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

        LatLng ll1 = new LatLng(40.4, -3.7);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll1, 17));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        if (mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude > 40.4) {
            mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));
        } else {
            mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json2));
        }
    }
}
```